# Assign image of one button to another vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a application in vb.net in which their are 10 button with images.
When I press any button in it I want the image of that button to be assigned to another button

Comment: If I remember right, you can simply assign it, don't you? Just like `button1.Image = button2.Image`.

Comment: Also, if you could include a code sample, any errors, or details on what you've tried so far.

Comment: Do you want the images to swap?  Are there any other buttons on the form that shouldn't participate in this described behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to imagine that you can just say `Button1.Image = Button2.Image`
If you want a button to change its image to the button you pressed, you could always use `ButtonX.Image = Sender.Image`, replacing X with the number of the button you'd like to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub picboxSub_Ass_Detail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Click

        If picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 0 Then
            picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Image = My.Resources.Tamp02
            picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 1
            GoTo a
        ElseIf picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 1 Then
            picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Image = My.Resources.Tamp01
            picboxSub_Ass_Detail.Tag = 0
            GoTo a
        End If
a:
    End Sub
```